# Error: Argument "documentRef" is not a valid DocumentReference. Couldn't serialize object of type "CollectionReference". FireStore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In order to update a document I do the following:

1) I collect the first part of the data from a document in a collection called `"Loc"`

2) I use a part of data from 1) to get a document in a collection called `"userInfo"`

3) I use results from 1) and 2) to update the second document

I used **Transaction** because I need this 3 actions to run all at once according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#passing_information_out_of_transactions), this is possible.

```
return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            var LocRef = db.collection("Loc").doc(newLocale);

            db.runTransaction(function (transaction) {
                return transaction.get(LocRef).then(function (doc) {
                    if (!doc.exists) {
                        throw "Document does not exist!";
                    }
                    var userInfoDocRef = userInfoRef.doc(user_id)
                    transaction.get(userInfoDocRef).then(function (userDoc) {
                        if (!userDoc.exists) {
                            throw "Document does not exist!";
                        }
                        var userInfoUpdate = {
                            "preferred_locale": newLocale,
                            "preferred_pair": userDoc.data().preferred_crypto_currency + doc.data().CurrencyCode,
                            "preferred_fiat_currency": doc.data().CurrencyCode
                        }
                        transaction.update(userInfoRef, userInfoUpdate);
                        var ans = {"success": true}
                        return ans
                    }).catch((e)=>{
                        console.log(e)
                    });
                }).then(function (ans) {
                    res(ans)
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    // This will be an "population is too big" error.
                    console.error(err);
                    rej(err)
                });
            })
        })
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error: Argument "documentRef" is not a valid DocumentReference.
>   Couldn't serialize object of type "CollectionReference" Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the 'new' operator).

Comment: There's code you're not showing here, including `userInfoRef`.  Also, it's a really bad idea to try to resolve a promise defined outside a transaction from within a transaction.  This will go very wrong if your transaction is repeated due to contention on the documents.  As the documentation you linked says: "Do not modify application state inside of your transaction functions".  You might want to rethink your implementation here.

Comment: just curious, why would `userData` document depend on `Loc-ation` document? The `userData` is the `userData` no matter the client location, right?